# histogram indexed by month and day

Tags: python, matplotlib, search, histogram, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a histogram of the number of month / day pairs. So, I have an array which consists of the following:

```
date_patterns = [(12,1,1992), (1,4,1993), (1,5,1993), 
                 (1,6,1993), (1,4,1994), (1,5,1994), 
                 (2,9,1995), (3,4,1995), (1,4,1996)]
```

I'd like this histogram indexed by just the month and day so:

```
(12,1) = 1
(1,4) = 3
(1,5) = 2
(1,6) = 1
(2,9) = 1
(3, 4) = 1
```

Comment: I suppose [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084574/plotting-histogram-of-list-of-tuplets-matplotlib/35085694) what you're looking for?

Comment: not quite - my data has years in the tuple which i'd like to ignore

Comment: Use `c=Counter([(a,b) for a,b,c in date_patterns])` and the rest is shown in the duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import itertools
date_patterns = [(12,1,1992), (1,4,1993), (1,5,1993), 
                 (1,6,1993), (1,4,1994), (1,5,1994), 
                 (2,9,1995), (3,4,1995), (1,4,1996)]

#use a list comprehension to go through the date patterns grouped by day, month and then count the lengths of the groups
groups = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in  itertools.groupby(sorted(date_patterns), lambda x:(x[0], x[1]))]

print groups
```